# How to Refresh the Registry Settings through VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, proxy, windows-7, dns, registrykey

I am modifying the Proxy settings by modifying the registry value.
After that i am rebooting my Windows 7 machine.But still it is taking approximately 10 minutes to reflect the changes even after system reboot.

Is there any way to refresh the settings instantaneously once the registry is updated ?

I have tried already to flush the DNS cache.

```
objShell.Run("ipconfig /flushdns"),1,True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh **Explorer.exe** by killing and running it like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = "Explorer.exe"
Refresh(ProcessName)
'*********************************************************************
Sub Refresh(ProcessName)
Kill(ProcessName)
RunIt(ProcessName)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Sub Kill(ProcessName)
Dim Ws : Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim Command : Command = "Taskkill /F /IM "& ProcessName &""
Dim Result : Result = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Sub RunIt(ProcessName)
Dim Ws : Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim Result : Result = Ws.Run(ProcessName,1,False)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
```